# Index (match - with dynamic array in different sheets in another excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying, with help from an Index(match), formula, to retrieve data from another file,
The challenge is that I want the array to be dynamic; as the file location (path) may vary, and the sheet name will differ.

I have tried to enter path in e.g cell A1, and workbook name in A2, sheet name in A3 (cell array will always be the total sheet), and used "concacenate" in order to have the whole path, filename and array. Unfortunately, - it gives med #REf.

I have also tried to write the whole path in the formula, with an " &A2' " to have the location + sheet name (the latter is entered into cell A2), but then a dialogue box appears stating "sheet A2 does not exist in the workbook". It appears i do not manage excel to understand that what is entered in A2 shall be used as input).

This formula was my starting point; '=INDIRECT("'["&B6&"]"&C6&"'!"&D6)
unfortunately - it does not include the pathfor the file location, and here's obviously something that trips me.

I've looked through this several times, and unfortunately I'm blinded for now - and cannot see where the error(s) might be.
Hope you can give me some great hints

Comment: INDIRECT requires that the target workbook be open.  If it is not open then you will get the #Ref error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Any other ideas how I might be able to solve the matter?

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to solve this problem using `INDIRECT()` (and other functions that WILL look in a different file if it is open, but not if it is closed) is to dedicate a portion of your spreadsheet to the collection of that data with formulas that WILL look into another spreadsheet, even when closed.

So you might have a very hidden page that collected some data from a closed spreadsheet. Then your "visible to your users" pages would actually refer to the data in the current spreadsheet, not its source in the closed spreadsheet. Easy enough. And you still might use `INDIRECT()` in this as the data could be organized so as to mirror its sources in various ways that `INDIRECT()`, and therefore you, could exploit.

The difficulty is that that all has to be built in. For instance, you might have a very hidden sheet for each file and the data might be collected via formulas like `='blah-blah'!A1` or whatever matches. So most of the elements would be there, and you could ask the user for, or to select, the filenames, paths, and so on, then actually make use of them slightly differently than straightforwardly to fit the idea that you are seeking answers in the close-to-mirrooring structure in THIS spreadsheet.

So, the difficulty? Well, depending on just how well you can do that with your method of seeking input, you might have no problem at all. For instance, selecting from a list you create (and maintain) gives you total control and total foresight. There's nothing they can feed in that you don't know ahead of time so you can structure your "transfer data" in a suitable way to deal with any combination you allow.

But... dynamic... that COULD mean that they enter, from whole cloth, paths and filenames, or even if not those, that they might enter data subsets (ranges) and if they enter the wrong information, it all tumbles down. If a range is A1:D4 and they enter C1:M28, well, there's no real way to overcome it without a nightmare of error-checking in your formula.

However, ranges themselves could even be Named Ranges in your user's spreadsheet. Certainly the data collection ought to use them (named in parallel to the ones your users will have available {so data collection uses something like "Input_Range" and the user uses or selects from a list "InputRange", that kind of parallel}) and so getting the right data rather than entering bizarre ranges just for... fun.

But to be really able to range far and wide? Formula-based approaches just can't do it without an interesting approach that's a bit complex to explain here. So what can you do?

If you want a live, often refreshed link to the data, Power Query can do that for you. A whole new thing to learn, but not only can it do it, but it has SQL "under the hood" but not to hide it from you, just to let you work in a way analagous to mousing to a file in a GUI rather than typing in a command window. It can be edited, and otherwise modified. Think of it being like a macro you RECORD, then edit to make it "just right." Advantages are the automatic refreshing, the buildable nature, its ability to use essentially unlimited data (hundreds of millions of rows, say), Excel files included, and the fact that a LOT of people, perhaps you included, know how to work in SQL already.

For absolute control though, moving to VBA would be the way to go. Error checking and placing limits on the users is a snap in VBA. There are lots of people who write VBA for folks, for money, if you do not know it well enough yourself. No shame there, you're hiring a skill and can learn from the work produced. A fun thing about VBA is that it can open files and extract data without the file being exposed to a user, if desired. It can follow any data path given, and handle errors in that easily. It can be extended with a couple other languages and various other languages have their own packages just for Excel if they are not ones Excel lets in. It also has absolute control over forms you can use instead of a raw sheet-side spreadsheet. Gold standard, really.

So it all hangs on just how much control over the inputs to the situation you have. If the users can enter any old thing, you have a nightmare ahead of you. If they have to select from validated lists, you can do it formula-wise. If you have the knowledge and/or money, Power Query and VBA offer almost perfect solutions. If not, well, there'd be a learning curve or some spending of money.

One thing no one can offer though:  `INDIRECT()` will NOT look into another file for you and no one has ever found a loophole in that or a way to coerce it into doing so.

Final thought, long enough already or not, is that VBA has the ability to trigger actions by seeing a cell modified, or even just clicked, or more traditionally, via a command button placed on the screen. So if you don't need something absolutely slick and impenetrable, and your users are tame creatures, you could record macros to open files and collect the appropriate data from each (so different places in them and so on), placing it in a sheet in your spreadsheet. Open, collect, and place for every file and range you plan to let them use, and your macro will have the commands in it from the recording to do each again. Then edit the macro to clear the sheet your data needs to be placed on and next put variables that collect the users' path, filename, and ranges from their inputs when they click a button (or even a cell you type "Click to load" inside). Use those variables to select the proper open/collect/place command from the recorded lines. Have the macro execute that collection command and end. Boom! The macro cleans up the middleman sheet, then your users' chosen parameters are used by the macro to open the proper file, select the proper range of data, and place it all in your spreadsheet where your show page's formulas can find it and do your magic. With that much, it's easy to set up, though it would be worrisome while you do so if you haven't done this before, and while it couldn't handle errors, or users' intentional efforts to trip it up, it WOULD function and nicely, if they behave.

And if desired, it could be improved over time by you as you have time and learn to do the next steps. You'd learn, you'd get practice you could apply to other things, and eventually, you'd practically have a program, not a spreadsheet.

Of course, once you got it working nicely, and people slowed down on the "Why don't you...?" stuff, you'd have a tested, fully spec'ed out program laid out and could easily engage a programmer to write a dedicated program for you outside Excel that would do it all via your company's own private program. All the usual set of fantastic price rise problems would be avoided so it might be very economical. We use spreadsheets in general for that idea here, and have our company's backbone program owners write unique functions and reports for us once we have all the kinks and needs worked out via the spreadsheets. You would just be doing that with VBA rather than the show page's work.